# The energy of efimov states increase with bigger or smaller states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, physical-chemistry

There are some sites like this answer of this site: [About Efimov States and Halo-Nuclei](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/about-efimov-states-and-halo-nuclei)

That says that the bigger the states the bigger its energy by a scaling factor of squared 22.7

But then there are site like these: https://www.quantamagazine.org/20140527-physicists-prove-surprising-rule-of-threes/

http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/16/2/023026

That say that the energy is smaller if the states are bigger by the same factor of 22.7 (squared)

I don't understand, they contradict each other! What happens then?

What are the highest and the lowest limits of energies of these states? Since there are infinite number of them, they don't have upper energy limit?

And for what could we use these "efimov molecules"? Could we make engines of batteries or other things with them?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a typo, the less deeply bound states are bigger. The binding energy scales as binding momentum squared, and the size scales as inverse binding momentum. This is not specific to Efimov states -- it is true for any quantum mechanical bound state.

If the two-body scattering length is truly infinite, then there are an infinite number of arbitrarily shallow (and large states), but any stable system will have to have a lowest (and smallest) Efimov trimer. The binding energy of that state is not universal. If the two-body scattering length is large, but not infinite, then there are a finite number of states.

And no, these states are of no obvious use.